# Delete link not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Board and List Models. On a Board show page i have Lists.

I am trying to delete a list. The problem is that when i click delete it goes to the destroy action on the Board Controller instead of the List Controller. How do i get the delete link to go the destroy action on my Lists Controller?

**Lists Controller**

```
def destroy
    @list = List.find(params[:id])
    @list.destroy
 end
```

**Boards Show View**

```
<% @lists.each do |list| %>

  <%= list.title %>  

  <%= link_to  "delete list", @list, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>

 <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= link_to  "delete list", @list, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
```

You're using `@list` here when you should use `list`

Try the following:

```
<%= link_to  "delete list", list, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
```

Also, in your ListsController#destroy action, you're going to need to render or redirect the user somewhere. I would put
`redirect_to :back` at the end of the destroy action.

Comment: I get can't modify frozen hash error. I assume that is because list has a child model too. I'm not sure why? I have dependent destroy on my models.

Comment: Nevermind i was only supposed to use dependent destroy on one model not both.